# Parse JSON to database with string only

Tags: c#, json, regex, parsing, datatable

I am using below code to parse JSON, I want to parse my JSON even if it has valid or invalid value or any value with space.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
string pattern = @"\""(?<key>[^\""]+)\""\:\""?(?<value>[^\"",}]+)\""?\,?";
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    if (m.Success)
    {
        values.Add(m.Groups["value"].Value);
        //keys.Add(m.Groups["key"].Value);
    }
}

result = values.ToArray();
```

I am facing challenge when any JSON value has space in it. Below JSON is parsing with empty value for that property.

```
{
 "Inquiry" : 1,
 "Number" :578
}
```

I receive Inquiry as empty string. What I should do in regex to make it work?

I want to bypass space between "Inquiry" and :

Comment: Your regex does not specify the possibility of whitespace appearing around `:`. However, it is not the right way. Use a JSON parser to convert the string into a JSON object and get the values you need from it.

Comment: The question is unclear. To parse Json use a Json parser like Json.NET. The Json snippet you posted is perfectly valid. I seriously doubt there is a single Regex that can parse Json and handle the *valid* whitespace and newlines inside string values, arrays of objects, and infinitely nested objects. A parser is *faster* than the multiple regex patters you'd need

Comment: I want to parse JSON with string values for all properties. Because I am validate each property data.

Comment: @k-s Just use Json.NET and parse it. Whitespace is *not* invalid. If you want to parse into a specific class, Json.NET allows you to do this with a simple `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(...)`

Comment: If I use Json.NET then such values in json like capital NULL, 008, 009 will not be parsed, 01 will be returned as 1 in JSON.parse. So I don't want to use it. Please guide me in above regex to allow whitespace after property and before colon.